# Bash scripting keyboard input

Tags: bash, shell

I am creating a bash script for generating certificates. The openssl command that creates a certificate asks for keyboard input. This is every time the same sequence of keys: seven times [ENTER] followed by two times ['y' + ENTER]. How can I do this programmatically?

#### Update

I was able to reduce eliminate the required keyboard input using the command line parameters:

- `-config FILE` to specify a config file
- `-passin PWD` and `-passout PWD` to specify a password

For more details you can have a look at [my experiments](https://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PlayGround/OCSP). This url is checkout-able with subversion.

Comment: i think this belongs on server fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to simulate user interaction is [expect](http://expect.nist.gov/).

With OpenSSL specifically, you could just write a configuration file that does not require any input for the task you want to perform. (see `man 5ssl config`)

For a good example of how to script opennssl, see [CACerts CSRGenerator script](http://svn.cacert.org/CAcert/Software/CSRGenerator/csr).

Comment: After perusing the man files I learned how to pass the required fields either as command line params or in a config file. Thanks.

Comment: @StackedCrooked - I have a similar problem. Can you post an answer with the command line or config file params that you used to solve this problem? I think me and others will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's asking for keyboard input, just give it something to read.

I suppose `yes | your_script` would work, otherwise you could just write the following sequence to its input:

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n\ny\ny\n
```

Answer (score 0):

[Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is pretty good at this kind of thing. Other languages will let you do this (far less conveniently) through their popen-style facilities.

You might be able to pipe the characters in as @tusbar suggests, but tools like openssl may insist on you typing it in (something *Expect* gets around by setting up pseudo-terminals).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to include input directly in your bash script:

```
interactive-program <<LimitString
command #1
command #2
...
LimitString
```

(But the configuration file option suggested by @hop is still the best idea).